# Which Kibana version supports Elastic Search 0.90.1

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

We are using Elastic Search 0.90.1 so which version of Kibana supports this Elastic Search version or to rephrase which Kibana is compatible with 0.90.1 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Kibana 3, the requirements found [here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/tree/v3.0.0) indicates that you need **Elasticsearch 0.90.9 or above**.

I searched for Kibana 2, and it could be compatible : the [readme](https://github.com/rashidkpc/Kibana) says that **elasticsearch >= 0.18.0** is required.

If you want to use Kibana 3, you'll have to upgrade to 0.90.9.

Answer (score 0):

Milestone 1 of Kibana 3 actually supported older versions of Elasticsearch.
I would recommend giving https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/releases/tag/v3.0.0-m1 a try.